# Responsive slider with slide height updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list where each item contains a text and an image:

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="txt"><p>First slogan</p></div>
      <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x180" /></div>      
    </li>
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need it to be responsive ... the img and txt divs scale on window resize.

After a certain point the img div becomes under the txt div as seen in codepen:

**[SLIDE EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/yAluo)**

**This is working fine** ... But now I need to make it work as a slider.

I am trying to make it using [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2) JQuery plugin:

**[SLIDE EXAMPLE WITH CYCLE 2](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/FHkBh)**

The height does not adapt to the slide content.

Could someone please help me out?

Thank you,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at their documentation [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/autoheight.php) it has plenty of options to adapt the height like adding 
`<div class="slider" data-cycle-auto-height="1:1">`

Hope that helps.

Comment: It helped a bit but didn't solve all my problems. I updated it in http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/FHkBh. 1 - I don't understand why the P tag at the end is displayed on top over the slogan text; 2 - I have no idea why the responsive behavior I created completely stops working when I apply the Cycle plugin. Any idea how to solve these?

Comment: the Cycle Plugin is completely re-structuring the HTML and so the CSS rules you have aren't getting applied anymore because it is taking the <ul> out on its own with no <li> as its children , if you can give me more information like why are you applying this to the `<li>` elements and not directly to the img elements? were you trying to get a caption added to the images? if so then the have an easier way of doing that like here [link](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caption.php)

Comment: and back to you first point the P tag is on top of the slogan because the slogan text and image are both positioned absolute from the plugin and are laying on top of it.

Comment: I see ... So that is not an option for me ... I created a new thread on this to do this manually. If you care to take a look I appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048949/fade-in-out-li-and-resize-containers-height