# Fade In / Out LI and Resize Container's Height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following markup (I created an [example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/eufCB) in Code Pen):

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li id="S1">
      <div class="txt"><p>First slogan</p></div>
      <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x180" /></div>      
    </li>
    <li id="S2">
      <div class="txt"><p>First slogan</p></div>
      <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x280" /></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#S1">1</a>
  <a href="#S2">2</a>
</div>
```

I would like to have the following:

1. Initially only the first LI item is visible.
2. When an A tag is clicked, if its href value, is not the ID of the visible LI then:

   - Fade out current LI;
   - Resize Slider container DIV Height to the height of the LI to be displayed.
   - Fade in the LI do be displayed.

How can I do this with JQuery?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this swap function should do the trick

First add the currentStory class to the first LI and A tags `<li id="S1" class="currentStory">`  `<a href="#S1" class="currentStory" id="S1">1</a>`

Make sure the links have the same ID as their `<li>` items for this to work

`<a href="#S1" class="currentStory" id="S1">1</a>`
  `<a href="#S2" id="S2">2</a>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function swapStory(storyName){
$('.slider li.currentStory').hide();
$('.slider li.currentStory').removeClass('currentStory');
$('.slider [id = ' + storyName + ']').addClass('currentStory');
$('.slider [id = ' + storyName + ']').fadeIn("slow");
  }

  $(function() {

     $('.slider li:not(".currentStory")').hide();
        $('.slider a').click(function(){
            swapStory($(this).attr("id"));
            return(false);
        });
   });

});
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example that i made, i cut out all the css rules and made them simple with jquery.

of course you'll need to put your media-queries back in it.

the Jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
       var id = $(this).attr('href').split("#").pop();
       var li = $('.slider ul li');
       $('.slider ul li').each(function(key,v){
           //if  linked to li is hidden show it
           if($(this).is(':hidden') && id == $(this).attr('id')){
                $(this).fadeIn(500).slideDown("fast");
            }
            //if it's alrready visible do nothing
            else if($(this).is(':visible') && id == $(this).attr('id')){
            }
            else{
               $(this).fadeOut(100,function(){$(this).slideUp("fast")});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ms7VE/1/)

Comment: I don't want to see one slide to push the other ... I would like fade so that effect is not visible.

Comment: @MDMoura ok, you could easily do it with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, check the updated code and jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

maybe using the jQueryUI accordion will solve your problem.

Check this : [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)